# Question about equation

Tags: soft-question

I have a basic question.

If I have an expression(Polynomial,logarithm,etc.) and it is told to me it's an equation, but it's is not written to what it's equal to, do we consider it by convention equal to 0 ???

For a certain reason, I don't remember this xD

Thank you !

Comment: You assume nothing.  The author of the question made a mistake.

Comment: I think your wording is correct. It's just an expression! I also don't believe that it's convention to set it equal to zero, unless the situation warrants otherwise. For example, if $f(t)$ is some expression in the variable $t$ which gives the height of an object at time $t$ and the question asks when does the height reach 3 (meters, say), then you equate the equation $f(t)=3$.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. THe author made a mistake because he gives a logarithmic expression and says it's an equation but doesn't put any equal sign or value.

Answer (score 2):

An equation equates.  An expression merely expresses.

You don't have an equation.  You have an expression.

There's no "default value" for an expression.